# How to share the Facebook Look Back?

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

I've read that you have to watch the video to be able to share, and like. There should be a share button, but on mine there is no video to watch. They're just photos, and if I click on them, it just takes me to the original place they were at.

I also had refreshed the page multiple times, yet the button does not show.

Answer (score 1):

https://m.facebook.com/lookback/share a direct share link will take you to the mobile desktop. Just click share & done =)